# Why does Magento randomly sort products in category list view and how can I fix that?

Tags: list, sorting, magento, categories

For one of our clients, I manage a Magento store. The problem with this one is that, even though I have selected an attribute to sort on, the order of the products in the category list view is randomized within values.
Maybe this will make it a bit clearer:
Say I have sorted the category by the "bla" attribute.
Say 30 products have value "aa" on the "bla" attribute and 30 other products have value "ab".
Then Magento will first show all products that have value "aa" on the "bla" attribute and then the 30 products that have value "ab" on the "bla" attribute.
So far so good. However, within the "aa" products, the order keeps changing randomly. Even when still browsing the same category. Since there are sometimes 100+ products that have the same value on the "bla" attribute, this can lead to some product being displayed on the first page of the category list view, but then we encounter it again on the 3rd or even 4th page. Of course, Magento should remember the order in which the products are displayed to ensure that page navigation can never throw duplicate products at me, right?
So.. What's happening? Is this standard Magento behavior?
More importantly: what can I do about it?
Searching Google, Stack Overflow, etc. did not help me at all, so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: there is no such thing as random! :)

Comment: I know that. It >seems< random. Not very helpful..

Comment: i know.  it was just a random comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set position for each product in category and when you open category page - products will be ordered by it:

[image]

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I actually use another attribute to sort on. If I were to use attribute "bla" and set positions, they would not be used, right?

Comment: No, position is always used for ordering with lowest priority as I know. So, you should have `ORDER BY price, position`. In any case, you can try set position for several products with attribute "bla" and see category page.

Comment: Thanks, we will try to figure out what we did wrong then. Because Position is uniquely filled for every product in the store and we still get this behavior.

Comment: This turned out to be an issue with a script someone else implemented into the Magento store to reset "user chosen" sort by. Thanks for all your help.